# Value based gridlines / divider in QTableView

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

I have a QTableView, which I feed with data from ODBC/SQL, where I sort the values firstly in "Team" and in "Person":

| Team | Person | RO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | PA | 11111 |
| A | PB | 11112 |
| A | PC | 11113 |
| B | PD | 11114 |
| B | PE | 11115 |
| C | PF | 11116 |

In the QTableView I know, that I can set the gridline via

```
tableWidget.setShowGrid(False)
tableWidget.setStyleSheet('QTableView::item {border-right: 1px solid #d6d9dc;}')
```

But I want to make a thick line between different "Teams", so between Person PC/PD and PE/PF should be a thick horizontal seperator on the full row.

How to do that? - I searched the web and dont find anything...

I thought I cloud do it with

```
QtCore.QAbstractTableModel
```

but I dont find a Role to give another borderline.

Thanks

Comment: That can be done, but it depends on the context: what if the table is sorted in a different order, using a different column? For instance, if the "person" or "ro" column are reversed.

Comment: I forbidded column rerange by the user - the column order would not be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution could be to override the paint event of the table and draw the "thicker" lines based on the data. For optimization reasons, the *rows* of those lines can be "cached", so that the only computation needed for painting is to get the coordinates for the lines.

The code below will give the following result:

[image: screenshot of the result]

```py
class TableSplitLines(QTableWidget):
    linesDirty = False
    penWidth = 3
    referenceColumn = 0
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.splitLines = []
        self.itemChanged.connect(self.markDirty)

    def markDirty(self):
        if not self.linesDirty:
            self.linesDirty = True
            self.update()

    def updateLines(self):
        '''
        Create a list of rows that correspond to the last rows that have common
        and contiguous values for the choosen column
        '''
        self.splitLines.clear()
        last = None
        for row in range(self.rowCount()):
            first = self.item(row, self.referenceColumn)
            if first is None:
                value = None
            else:
                value = first.text()
            if row == 0:
                last = value
            elif value != last:
                self.splitLines.append(row)
                last = value
        self.linesDirty = False

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.linesDirty:
            self.updateLines()

        if self.splitLines:
            # get the right edge of the last visible column
            hHeader = self.horizontalHeader()
            lastSection = -1
            for i in range(self.columnCount()):
                logical = hHeader.logicalIndex(i)
                if not hHeader.isSectionHidden(logical):
                    lastSection = logical

            right = min(self.viewport().width(), 
                hHeader.sectionPosition(lastSection)
                + hHeader.sectionSize(lastSection)
                - hHeader.offset() 
            )

            extent = self.penWidth // 2 + 1
            top = event.rect().y() - extent
            bottom = event.rect().bottom() + extent

            # get the grid color from the current style
            opt = QStyleOption()
            opt.initFrom(self)
            gridColor = QColor.fromRgb(
                self.style().styleHint(
                    QStyle.SH_Table_GridLineColor, opt, self
                ) & 0xffffff)

            qp = QPainter(self.viewport())
            qp.setPen(QPen(gridColor, self.penWidth, cap=Qt.FlatCap))

            # draw lines as long as they're included in the event rect
            vHeader = self.verticalHeader()
            offset = vHeader.offset() + 1
            for row in self.splitLines:
                y = vHeader.sectionPosition(row) - offset
                if y < top:
                    continue
                elif y > bottom:
                    break
                qp.drawLine(0, y, right, y)

        # call the base implementation
        super().paintEvent(event)
```

Note: the `0xffffffff` mask is caused by the fact that the value returned by `styleHint()` is an unsigned int, but due to the dynamic typing of Python it can be interpreted as a *signed* (so, possibly negative).

Comment: Thank you! :-)
I only got an error at:
`gridColor = QColor.fromRgb(self.style().styleHint(QStyle.SH_Table_GridLineColor, opt, self))`
This: `OverflowError: argument 1 overflowed: value must be in the range 0 to 4294967295`

Comment: @LukasFürst Uhm, try changing those two lines with the following `gridColor = QColor.fromRgb(self.style().styleHint(QStyle.SH_Table_GridLineColor, opt, self) & 0xffffffff)`